# How can you take a square root of a negative number?

Tags: radicals

How can you take a square root of a negative number?

Specifically, I have this problem where I need to select a positive integer $q$ s.t. for $b \in ]2,5[$, $$q > \sqrt{\frac{1}{b-5}}$$ and I want to be able to conclude that $$b < 5-\frac{1}{q^2}$$

And the reason that $q$ has to be selected this way is of course:

$$b < 5-\frac{1}{q^2}$$
$$bq^2 < 5q^2-1$$
$$q^2(b-5)< -1$$

and since $b-5 < 0$ ($b \in ]2,5[$)

$$q^2 > \frac{1}{b-5}$$

But how can I select such $q$?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Do you want a $q$ in terms of $b$ such that $q^2>\frac{1}{b-5}$ $\forall\, b\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @LukeCollins $b \in ]2,5[$?

Comment: Where did that condition come from?

Comment: How did the problem start? I ask because $q>\sqrt {1/(b-5) } $ does not actually make sense for $b <5$. However $q^2 >1/(b-5) $ does (and will hold for all real $q $).

Comment: @LukeCollins it's related to the problem where I have this problem of selecting the $q$. Read the question?

Comment: Just as @Ian said, there can be no such $q\in\mathbb Z^+$.

Comment: You mean I cannot select such $q$? But how am I then supposed to display that $b < 5 - \frac{1}{q^2}$ for some $q$, because obviously that's true, if $b \in ]2,5[$.

Comment: Could it be possible that since I want $q^2 > \frac{1}{b-5}$ then I could merely pick any $q > 0$ since $q^2 \ge 0$ in any case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an error on taking the reciprocals: the smaller becomes the larger.

Explicitly,
\begin{align}
q>\frac1{\sqrt{b-5}}&\iff q^2>\frac1{b-5}\quad\textbf{and}\quad b-5>0\\
&\iff b-5>\frac1{q^2}\quad\textbf{and}\quad b-5>0\\
&\iff 5<b<5+\frac1{q^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: How can $b-5 > 0$ if $b \in ]2,5[$?

Comment: I didn't even see this hypothesis. It means you can't select such an integer: $b$ is not in the domain of the inequation.  Are you sure of the exact form of the inequation?

Comment: I know that it has to be that $b \in ]2,5[$. I also know that the interval $]2,5[$ is the limit of $[2+i^{-2}, 5- i^{-2}]$, thus why I need the inequalities, such as $b < 5-i^{-2}$.

Comment: Isn't it $q>\dfrac1{\sqrt{\lvert b-5\rvert}}$?

Comment: Probably yes it is.

Comment: Then replace $b-5$ with $5-b$, and you'll obtain $5-\dfrac1{q^2}<b<5$.